# Oracle SQL - Query to calculate values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Am trying to get desired results from sql query by joining multiple tables. Since am having limited knowledge, seeking help from you all.

Am trying to get audit details per manager and employees. I have 3 tables:

```
1. HR
2. REQUIRED_AUDITS
3. SCORE_ENTRY
```

Below is the sample data for **HR** Table:

```
+----+---------------+------------------+
| id | manager_email |        VP        |
+----+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | john@com.com  | jake@com.com     |
|  2 | smith@com.com | kathleen@com.com |
|  3 | maria@com.com | james@com.com    |
|  4 | linda@com.com | david@com.com    |
|  5 | jess@com.com  | kim@com.com      |
+----+---------------+------------------+
```

Below is the sample data for **REQUIRED_AUDITS** table:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID | manager_email | employee_email | audits_required | audit_eligible |
+----+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|  1 | john@com.com  | brad@com.com   |               5 | Y              |
|  2 | linda@com.com | gloria@com.com |               2 | Y              |
|  3 | linda@com.com | susan@com.com  |               7 | Y              |
|  4 | john@com.com  | carmen@com.com |               5 | Y              |
|  5 | linda@com.com | aaron@com.com  |              25 | N              |
+----+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Below is the sample data for **SCORE_ENTRY** table:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+-------+
| ID | manager_email | employee_email | Score |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------+
|  1 | linda@com.com | gloria@com.com | 85.04 |
|  2 | linda@com.com | susan@com.com  |   100 |
|  3 | john@com.com  | carmen@com.com | 80.50 |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------+
```

So now I want to show number of audits required for each manager and how many completed and also percentage of completion.

```
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Manager(list from "HR" table) | Total Audits Required(Sum of audits required from "REQUIRED_AUDITS table") | Audits Performed(from "SCORE_ENTRY" table) | Percentage Completion |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| john@com.com                  |                                                                         10 |                                          1 | 10%                   |
| linda@com.com                 |                                                                          9 |                                          2 | 22.22%                |
| smith@com.com                 |                                                                          - |                                          - | -                     |
| maria@com.com                 |                                                                          - |                                          - | -                     |
| jess@com.com                  |                                                                          - |                                          - | -                     |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Calculations are as per below:
1. To calculate number of audits i.e., from **REQUIRED_AUDITS** table:
Considering manager linda@com.com:
Total audits required: 7+3 because only two employees are eligible
2. Total audits completed:
audits_required (from REQUIRED AUDITS table) - audits completed (from SCORE_ENTRY table)

As said am having limited knowledge on sql and this look really complex for me and hence reaching out in Stack Overflow.

Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**
To further simplify the process, I wrote discrete queries excluding HR table and need help in combining below queries.

Query 1: I call this as **"DENOMINATOR"**:

```
SELECT required_audits.manager_email, 
       SUM(audits_required) AS "TOTAL_AUDITS_REQUIRED" 
FROM   required_audits 
WHERE  Upper(required_audits.audit_eligible) = Upper('Y') 
GROUP  BY required_audits.manager_email 
ORDER  BY "total_audits_required" DESC 

+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| required_audits.manager_email | TOTAL_AUDITS_REQUIRED |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| john@com.com                  |                    10 |
| linda@com.com                 |                     9 |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Query 2: I call this as **"NUMERATOR"**:

```
SELECT score_entry.manager_email, 
       Count(id) 
FROM   score_entry 
GROUP  BY score_entry.manager_email 

+---------------------------+-----------+
| score_entry.manager_email | Count(id) |
+---------------------------+-----------+
| john@com.com              |         1 |
| linda@com.com             |         2 |
+---------------------------+-----------+
```

In the final or result, all I need is NUMERATOR**/**DENOMINATOR * 100 in percent. Am getting confused in joins and applying conditions in where clause.

```
+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|    Manager    | Total Audits Required | Audits Performed | Percentage Completion |
+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| john@com.com  |                    10 |                1 | 10%                   |
| linda@com.com |                     9 |                2 | 22.22%                |
+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

On result table, only audit eligible numbers should show up. This is another reason where am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: Your original result set shows **all** managers in HR table. Your second result set shows only managers with staff in the REQUIRED_AUDITS table. We cannot provide a solution if you keep changing the requirement. Please edit your question to make it consistent throughout.

Comment: @APC. Thanks fro the feedback. I was trying to explain the same original OP in more simplified terms. I wasn't sure that would create confusion. I gave a thought for your suggestion on why to have HR table because am technically gathering information from REQUIRED_AUDITS table and SCORE_ENTRY table. Now am thinking I do need HR table because that has few more columns like first name, last name, phone number etc so felt it will be good to include HR table. To simplify the data I did not include those columns. If I need to use first name of manager then I will have to join HR table. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use multiple common table expressions, computing each separately and joining together - just for you to understand what's going on.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f1d/34)

**Query**:

```
WITH aud(manager_email,Total_audits) AS
  (SELECT manager_email,
    SUM (
    CASE
      WHEN audit_eligible = 'Y'
      THEN audits_required
    END )
  FROM REQUIRED_AUDITS
  GROUP BY manager_email
  ),  --Total_audits

  scores(manager_email,Audits_Performed) AS
  (SELECT manager_email,
    COUNT ( ID )
  FROM SCORE_ENTRY s
  GROUP BY manager_email
  )  --Audits_Performed

SELECT h.manager_email manager,
  a.Total_audits,
  s.Audits_Performed,
  100 * s.Audits_Performed / a.Total_audits percentage_complete
FROM HR h
LEFT OUTER JOIN aud a
ON h.manager_email = a.manager_email
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores s
ON h.manager_email = s.manager_email
ORDER BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f1d/34/0)**:

```
|       MANAGER | TOTAL_AUDITS | AUDITS_PERFORMED | PERCENTAGE_COMPLETE |
|---------------|--------------|------------------|---------------------|
|  john@com.com |           10 |                1 |                  10 |
| linda@com.com |            9 |                2 |   22.22222222222222 |
| smith@com.com |       (null) |           (null) |              (null) |
|  jess@com.com |       (null) |           (null) |              (null) |
| maria@com.com |       (null) |           (null) |              (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik. This works fine in SQL Fiddle but when I run in my instance am getting error ORA-32040: recursive WITH clause must use a UNION ALL operation. This terminologies are all new to me. Sorry.

Comment: @Richa : That should not be the case, which version of Oracle are you using? It is also possible that while editing you may have modified something.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik. Am using 11gR2 version. I might have modified something while editing. My bad

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik Nayak. The code provided by APC is working fine. I will try your code once again and let you know. Much appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik. This query worked even after adding multiple identical rows in score entry.

Answer (score 1):

Given the posted data there is no need to use `HR` table in this query as the `manager_email` is also on the `required_audits` table. In real life using a column like  `manager_email` as the foreign would be a really bad idea. It should be the `hr.id` column.

Nevertheless I have included it in the query because you requested that.

The arithmetic is fairly straightforward. The complication is that you need to use `left outer join` to HR to REQUIRED_AUDITS because not all managers have employees who need auditing, and also to join to SCORE_ENTRY because not all employees have been audited.

```
select hr.manager_email
       , sum(ra.audits_required) as tot_audits_required
       , count(se.score) as audits_performed
       , (count(se.score) / sum(ra.audits_required)) * 100 as pct_complete      
from hr
left outer join ( select * from  REQUIRED_AUDITS 
                  where audit_eligible = 'Y') ra 
    on ra.manager_email = hr.manager_email
left outer join SCORE_ENTRY se 
    on se.employee_email = ra.employee_email
group by hr.manager_email
order by hr.manager_email
/
```

Demo on [Oracle LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f9a7m69f9cgddgp8dipoyv3oz).

---

> "On result table, only audit eligible numbers should show up."

To implement this version of the requirements simply turn the `left outer join` on REQUIRED_AUDITS into an `inner join`.

Comment: Thanks @APC. This is amazing. I tried adding one line of data to "SCORE_ENTRY" table ie., aaron@com.com who is not eligible for audit. When I do so, on the final output under column "TOT_AUDITS_REQUIRED", am getting value 34 instead of 9 for manager linda@com.com. Can you please let me know how to modify the original query to incorporate this? The reason I used HR table is to show details at VP level just in case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the table data in updated question as you suggested there's no need of HR table data. I was going with your suggestion. Sorry if it created confusion. I might have done something wrong when editing.

Comment: Thanks and I totally understand. Sorry for all the confusion. I really appreciate your time and help

Comment: I tried with cool mind and took more time to go thru each and every line of query. It's working like a charm. I also added validations on front end of system where not eligible employees are not added to score table. Thanks for the help and time. I really appreciate.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to round percent column? I tried adding another line **round((count(se.score) / sum(ra.audits_required)) * 100,2) as percent ** and **round((count(se.score) / sum(ra.audits_required)),2) as other_method_percent** and am getting error " ORA-00904: "RA"."AUDITS_REQUIRED": invalid identifier". Thanks

Comment: Thanks @APC. I will try my best to get it right.. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Tried this **round((( Count(se.score) / SUM(ra.required_audits) ) * 100 ),2)** and it worked. I think issue was with parenthesis. Am sure I did not change any column names. Thanks

Comment: If I add another row in score entry form *linda@com.com | gloria@com.com  |   100* Then the final output under column tot_audits_required is showing 11 (after debugging each join I could see its adding 9+2=11) instead of 9. If I add *susan@com.com*, am getting 11+7=18 instead of 9. Not sure how to fix that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well the proper solution would be to **fix the data model** , adding a primary or unique key which would prevent you inserting duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks @APC and am sorry if I didn't explain it right in OP. My apologies. The **"REQUIRED_AUDITS"** table will contain unique value where each employee will be given number of audits required per head. If employee **susan@com.com** has **5** audits, then in **SCORE_ENTRY** table there will be maximum of 5 entries for **susan@com.com**. When I say 5 entries, its 5 rows for **susan@com.com** with different scores or same scores. I should have explained it with more details. My bad. In parallel am learning how to post questions on stack overflow. Thanks for all the inputs and help.

Comment: Unfortunately much of our time on this site is spent on the tedious task of  teaching people how to ask good questions rather than on solving their programming problem (which is the fun bit).

Comment: lol.. agree. I will keep it in mind and explain with more details going forward. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

assuming from your sample score table above has we are to look at the qty of the scored rows and not the score this should help

```
select 
RA.manager_email, 
sum(RA.audits_requiered) as ReqQty,
(select count(manager_email) from SCORE_ENTRY as SE where SE.manager_email = RA.manager_email) as Compleated 

from REQUIRED_AUDITS as RA
group by manager_email
where audit_eligable='Y'
```

with the score table I was unclear if that is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @Job Cluff. You are absolutely right. Its the quantity of scored rows not the score itself. When I executed the code, am getting error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. For me visually it looked fine but for some reason am getting this error.

Comment: select 
RA.manager_email, 
sum(RA.audits_requiered) as ReqQty,
(select count(manager_email) from SCORE_ENTRY as SE where SE.manager_email = RA.manager_email) as Compleated 

from REQUIRED_AUDITS as RA
where audits_eligable='Y'
group by manager_email

Comment: When answering questions which are tagged `[oracle]` please be sure to use valid Oracle syntax, especially when the OP has identified themselves as a beginner. The ORA-00907 error is because your code uses `as` for table aliases which is not valid for Oracle.

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to help