# Oracle SQL newbie - Add new column that gets occurrence and computations

Tags: sql, oracle, count

This post is enhanced version of my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724137/oracle-sql-query-to-calculate-values-from-multiple-tables/48724526?noredirect=1#comment84607750_48724526).

*Please Note: This is not duplicate post or thread.*

I have 3 tables:

```
1. REQUIRED_AUDITS (Independent table)
2. SCORE_ENTRY (SCORE_ENTRY is One to Many relationship with ERROR table)
3. ERROR
```

Below are the dummy data and table structure:
**REQUIRED_AUDITS TABLE**

```
+-------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+
|  ID   |  VP  | Director |    Manager    |    Employee     | Req_audits | Audit_eligible | Quarter |
+-------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+
| 10001 | John | King     | susan@com.com | jake@com.com    |          2 | Y              | FY18Q1  |
| 10002 | John | King     | susan@com.com | beth@com.com    |          4 | Y              | FY18Q1  |
| 10003 | John | Maria    | tony@com.com  | david@com.com   |          6 | N              | FY18Q1  |
| 10004 | John | Maria    | adam@com.com  | william@com.com |          3 | Y              | FY18Q1  |
| 10005 | John | Smith    | alex@com.com  | rose@com.com    |          6 | Y              | FY18Q1  |
+-------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+------------+----------------+---------+
```

**SCORE_ENTRY TABLE**

```
+----------------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------+---------+
| SCORE_ENTRY_ID |  VP  | Director |    Manager    |    Employee     | Score | Quarter |
+----------------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------+---------+
|              1 | John | King     | susan@com.com | jake@com.com    |   100 | FY18Q1  |
|              2 | John | King     | susan@com.com | jake@com.com    |    90 | FY18Q1  |
|              3 | John | King     | susan@com.com | beth@com.com    | 98.45 | FY18Q1  |
|              4 | John | King     | susan@com.com | beth@com.com    |    95 | FY18Q1  |
|              5 | John | King     | susan@com.com | beth@com.com    |   100 | FY18Q1  |
|              6 | John | King     | susan@com.com | beth@com.com    |   100 | FY18Q1  |
|              7 | John | Maria    | adam@com.com  | william@com.com |    99 | FY18Q1  |
|              8 | John | Maria    | adam@com.com  | william@com.com |  98.1 | FY18Q1  |
|              9 | John | Smith    | alex@com.com  | rose@com.com    |    96 | FY18Q1  |
|             10 | John | Smith    | alex@com.com  | rose@com.com    |   100 | FY18Q1  |
+----------------+------+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

**ERROR TABLE**

```
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------+
| ERROR_ID |            ERROR            | SCORE_ENTRY_ID |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------+
|       10 | Words Missing               |              2 |
|       11 | Incorrect document attached |              2 |
|       12 | No results                  |              3 |
|       13 | Value incorrect             |              4 |
|       14 | Words Missing               |              4 |
|       15 | No files attached           |              4 |
|       16 | Document read error         |              7 |
|       17 | Garbage text                |              8 |
|       18 | No results                  |              8 |
|       19 | Value incorrect             |              9 |
|       20 | No files attached           |              9 |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

**I have query that give below output:**

```
+----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          |               | Director Summary |                  |                  |
+----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Director | Manager       | Audits Required  | Audits Performed | Percent Complete |
| King     | susan@com.com | 6                | 6                | 100%             |
| Maria    | adam@com.com  | 3                | 2                | 67%              |
| Smith    | alex@com.com  | 6                | 2                | 33%              |
+----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Now I would like to add column where **I want the number of scores that have an error associated with them divided by total count of scores**:

It's not total count of errors divided by count of scores. Instead its count of each occurrence of error and divide by count of score. 
Please find below example:

Considering

**Director:King**
**Manager:susan@com.com**

From **SCORE_ENTRY** TABLE and **ERROR** table,

- King has 6 entries in SCORE_ENTRY TABLE
- 6 entries in ERROR TABLE

**Instead of 6 entries in ERROR TABLE, I would like to have occurrence of error ie., 3 errors.**

Formula to calculate Quality:
**Quality = 1 - (sum of error occurrence / total score)*100**

For King:
Quality = 1 - (3/6)*100
Quality = 50

**Please Note:** It's not 1 - (6/6)*100

For Maria: 
Quality = 1 - (2/2)*100
Quality = 0

Below is the new output I need with new column called Quality:

```
+----------+---------------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          |               |         | Director Summary |                  |                  |
+----------+---------------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Director | Manager       | Quality | Audits Required  | Audits Performed | Percent Complete |
| King     | susan@com.com | 50%     | 6                | 6                | 100%             |
| Maria    | adam@com.com  | 0%      | 3                | 2                | 67%              |
| Smith    | alex@com.com  | 50%     | 6                | 2                | 33%              |
+----------+---------------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Below is the query am having (Thanks to @Kaushik Nayak, @APC and others) and need to add new column to this query:

```
WITH aud(manager_email, director, quarter, total_audits_required) 
     AS (SELECT manager_email, 
                director, 
                quarter, 
                SUM (CASE 
                       WHEN audit_eligible = 'Y' THEN required_audits 
                     END) 
         FROM   required_audits 
         GROUP  BY manager_email, 
                   director, 
                   quarter), --Total_audits 
     scores(manager_email, director, quarter, audits_completed) 
     AS (SELECT manager_email, 
                director, 
                quarter, 
                Count (score) 
         FROM   oq_score_entry s 
         GROUP  BY manager_email, 
                   director, 
                   quarter) --Audits_Performed 
SELECT a.director, 
       a.manager_email manager, 
       a.total_audits_required, 
       s.audits_completed, 
       Round(( ( s.audits_completed ) / ( a.total_audits_required ) * 100 ), 2) 
                       percentage_complete, 
       a.quarter 
FROM   aud a 
       left outer join scores s 
                    ON a.manager_email = s.manager_email 
WHERE  ( :P4_MANAGER_EMAIL = a.manager_email 
          OR :P4_MANAGER_EMAIL IS NULL ) 
       AND ( :P4_DIRECTOR = a.director 
              OR :P4_DIRECTOR IS NULL ) 
       AND ( :P4_QUARTER = a.quarter 
              OR :P4_QUARTER IS NULL ) 
ORDER  BY a.total_audits_required DESC nulls last
```

Please let me know if its confusing or need more details. Am open for any suggestions and feedback.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: Your question is very long and many people will find it hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I did explain with more details because that was the feedback I received from previous post. In simple terms, all I need is generate final output table from the 3 tables am having on top.

Comment: As a starting point have you tried  anything along the lines of;.    left outer join (select count(*),  SCORE_ENTRY_ID from error_table group by SCORE_ENTRY_ID) on SCORE_ENTRY_ID = entry_id

Comment: Hi @LJ01 I did try separate or stand alone query but I couldn't make it as it was so confusing for me. I got output as 1 but when I do sum of output, it gave error something like too much nesting. Am not remembering exact error though. Need help in figuring out query that fits within the WITH Clause because original WITH Clause is working fine. I don't know how to append new query inside WITH Clause either. Thanks

Comment: Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. I have modified the question and keeping it minimal and simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Well my first guess has been wrong, and I hope now I'm getting it right.

According to your and shawnt00's comments, you need to compute the count of score entries that have corresponding entries in ERROR table, and use it in quality calculation.
This count you get with the expression:

```
COUNT ((select max(1) from "ERROR" o where o.score_entry_id=s.score_entry_id)) AS error_occurences
```

max(1) returns 1 when there is an entry in "ERROR" and NULL otherwise. COUNT skips nulls.
I hope this is clear.

Quality is computed as

```
(1 - error_occurences/audits_completed)*100%
```

Below is the full script, where manager_email renamed to manager and oq_score_entry renamed to score_entry.
This is in accordance with your scheme. Also I removed unnecessary WITH column mapping, it just complicates things in this case.

```
WITH aud AS (SELECT manager, director, quarter, SUM (CASE 
                   WHEN audit_eligible = 'Y' THEN req_audits 
                 END) total_audits_required 
     FROM   required_audits 
     GROUP  BY manager, director, quarter), --Total_audits 
 scores AS (
 SELECT manager, director, quarter, 
            Count (score) audits_completed,
            COUNT ((select max(1) from "ERROR" o where o.score_entry_id=s.score_entry_id)
                    ) error_occurences -- **  Added **
     FROM   score_entry s 
     GROUP  BY manager, director, quarter
               ) --Audits_Performed 
SELECT a.director, 
   a.manager manager, 
   a.total_audits_required, 
   s.audits_completed, 
   Round(( 1 - ( s.error_occurences ) / ( s.audits_completed )) * 100, 2), -- **  Added **
   Round(( ( s.audits_completed ) / ( a.total_audits_required ) * 100 ), 2) 
                   percentage_complete, 
   a.quarter 
FROM   aud a 
   left outer join scores s ON a.manager = s.manager 
WHERE  ( :P4_manager = a.manager 
      OR :P4_manager IS NULL ) 
   AND ( :P4_DIRECTOR = a.director 
          OR :P4_DIRECTOR IS NULL ) 
   AND ( :P4_QUARTER = a.quarter 
          OR :P4_QUARTER IS NULL ) 
ORDER  BY a.total_audits_required DESC nulls last
```

**About `total_errors`:**

To add this column you can either use a technique similar to the one used before in `scores`:

```
scores AS (
    SELECT manager, director, quarter, 
           count (score) audits_completed,
           count ((select max(1) from "ERROR" o where o.score_entry_id=s.score_entry_id )
                   ) error_occurences,
           sum ( ( SELECT count(*) from "ERROR" o where o.score_entry_id=s.score_entry_id ) 
                   ) total_errors  -- summing error counts for matched score_entry_ids
    FROM   score_entry s 
    GROUP  BY manager, director, quarter
              )
```

Or you can rewrite the `scores` CTE joining `score_entry` and `error`, and that would require using `DISTINCT` on `score_entry` fields to avoid duplication of rows:

```
scores AS (
     SELECT manager, director, quarter, 
            count(DISTINCT s.score_entry_id) audits_completed,
            count(DISTINCT e.score_entry_id ) error_occurences, -- counting distinct score_entry_ids present in Error
            count(e.score_entry_id) total_errors -- counting total rows in Error
     FROM   score_entry s 
                LEFT JOIN "ERROR" e ON s.score_entry_id=e.score_entry_id
     GROUP  BY manager, director, quarter
               )
```

The latter approach is a bit less maintable, since it requires to be careful about unwanted duplication.

Yet another (and may be the most proper) way is to make a separate(third) CTE, but I don't think the query is complex enough to warrant this.

---

Original answer:
I might be wrong, but it seems to me that by "count of each occurrence of error" you are trying to describe COUNT(DISTINCT expr). That is to count unique occurences of error for each (manager_email, director, quarter). 
If so, change the query a bit:

```
WITH aud(manager_email, director, quarter, total_audits_required) 
 AS (SELECT manager_email, 
            director, 
            quarter, 
            SUM (CASE 
                   WHEN audit_eligible = 'Y' THEN required_audits 
                 END) 
     FROM   required_audits 
     GROUP  BY manager_email, 
               director, 
               quarter), --Total_audits 
 scores(manager_email, director, quarter, audits_completed, distinct_errors) 
 AS (SELECT manager_email, 
            director, 
            quarter, 
            Count (score),
            COUNT (DISTINCT o.error_id) -- **  Added **
     FROM   oq_score_entry s join error o on o.score_entry_id=s.score_entry_id 
     GROUP  BY manager_email, 
               director, 
               quarter) --Audits_Performed
SELECT a.director, 
   a.manager_email manager, 
   a.total_audits_required, 
   s.audits_completed, 
   Round(( ( s.distinct_errors ) / ( s.audits_completed ) * 100 ), 2) quality, -- **  Added **
   Round(( ( s.audits_completed ) / ( a.total_audits_required ) * 100 ), 2) 
                   percentage_complete, 
   a.quarter 
FROM   aud a 
   left outer join scores s 
                ON a.manager_email = s.manager_email 
WHERE  ( :P4_MANAGER_EMAIL = a.manager_email 
      OR :P4_MANAGER_EMAIL IS NULL ) 
   AND ( :P4_DIRECTOR = a.director 
          OR :P4_DIRECTOR IS NULL ) 
   AND ( :P4_QUARTER = a.quarter 
          OR :P4_QUARTER IS NULL ) 
ORDER  BY a.total_audits_required DESC nulls last
```

Comment: Thanks @wolfrevokcats. I haven't tried this query yet but would like to say that I want number of scores that have an error associated with them. That goes into numerator and total score goes into denominator for any given director or manager for the quarter

Comment: @Richa, I've updated my answer to match your clarification.

Comment: Hi @wolfrevokcats. I tried the query you provided and its showing 6 errors for King instead of 3. Its taking total count instead of one occurrence for repeated score_entry_id's.

Comment: Hi @wolfrevokcats. Fantastic fantastic. Awesome.. the updated query worked like a charm. You saved my day. You are so talented. Please let me know how I can learn and write queries like you did. Can you please let me know any books or materials I can study

Comment: Thank you, @Richa, I'm glad I've helped. Frankly, that sql didn't require any talent, the only obstacle was to understand what you need.  Speaking about books and materials, when I started working with Oracle I was reading only the official docs for several years, and no books at all. There is a ton of Oracle docs to read before you start making things right. Think twice if you are going into this.

Comment: Am trying to get another column that shows "total errors". Is it possible to modify existing query to do it? Appreciate any help.
Tried below code inside **with** clause:
`select manager, director, quarter,  count(error)
from score_entry s left outer join error e
    on e.score_entry_id = se.score_entry_id
group by manager, director, quarter`.  Not sure if I can put this inside aud table or scores table or should it be on separate table.

Comment: @Richa, updated the asnwer, see  **about total_errors** (in the middle)

Comment: am becoming huge fan of you. Thank you so much for helping me again on this. I spent days and days to get the first query that you provided. But couldn't succeed. All I knew was getting headache. Hence thought of simple approach and wrote the stand alone query. Again failed on where to put that code. Now with your answer, I feel like flying. Thanks again for all the help and for your precious time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The join on your main query will need to include director and quarter once you have more data.

I suppose the easiest way to fix this is to follow the structure you've got and add another table expression joining it to the rest of your results in the same way as the original two.

```
select manager_email, director, quarter,
    100.0 - 100.0 * count (distinct e.score_entry_id) / count (*) as quality
from score_entry se left outer join error e
    on e.score_entry_id = se.score_entry_id
group by manager_email, director, quarter
```

What would have made most of your explanation unnecessary is to have simply said that you want the number of scores that have an error associated with them. It was difficult to draw that out from the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00. You are absolutely right. It would have been fairly simple if I said that I want number of scores that have an error associated with them. That's wht I want. Thanks for correcting me. Am learning lot from each post. Also I wanted to let everybody know what I tried and where I went wrong. I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: I won't complain as much about extra information as missing information. At some point though it becomes too much work to read through and filter out the noise. And remember none of us are getting paid to help so we expect a good effort from you to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: Understood. I agree. Thanks again am updating the question

Comment: Hi @shawnt00. I tried the query you provided and its showing 6 errors for King instead of 3. Its taking total count instead of one occurrence for repeated score_entry_id's.

Comment: Don't count se.score_entry_id. Make sure it's from e.

Comment: am not sure why you feel offended. Pls excuse me if I was wrong. Sorry. It's you the one who taught me on how to phrase and simplify the question. Am always thankful to you. I tried your query earlier as standalone code but wasn't sure where to put it in the WITH clause